# National Weather Service GET request 400 error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Receiving 400 error for this simple NWS GET request for a point JSON dataset.  The jQuery process is inserting extra text after the initial set of parameters -https://api.weather.gov/points/39.5,-105.5?_=1630348301730.  The expected URL should end after the longitude value of -105.5.  I'm using the jQuery AJAX code below.  I've also tried the dataType as 'html' with the same result.  The URL is valid as it returns a well-formed JSON object when placed in the browser.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.weather.gov/points/39.5,-105.5",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json"
  })
    .done(function( html ) {
      $( "#results" ).append( html );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `cache: false,`

As the [jQuery docs for the cache option](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) explain:

> "...works by appending `_={timestamp}` to the GET parameters. The
> parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8
> when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a
> GET."